# How can I search YouTube including description and sort by date?

Tags: youtube, search

When I search YouTube normally, it finds matches including in video descriptions. But if I sort the results by upload date, then most of the videos are removed from the search, and it seems to only search for the phrase in the video title.

Is there any way to sort by date and still have YouTube search the video description? I'm trying to search for all videos that mention a product including in their description, and I need to sort by date so I can easily tell which videos are new. Unfortunately Google alerts no longer monitors YouTube.